# React-Native: loading animation performance

Tags: performance, react-native

I have an app that in several places has the following pattern:

1. User presses a button that sends out a backend api call. (E.g. they press the login button after entering credentials)
2. The app replaces the button with an animation that indicates processing. (E.g. some spinner replaces the login button)
3. The api call returns some result, triggering a navigation to the next scene.

The problem is that I suspect that this is bad for performance. At any given time the app is either rendering both a spinner while making api calls or the app is rendering a spinner while having a navigation animation to the next scene. I'm noticing substantial frame-rate decline during these kinds of transitions.

React-Native's performance documentation suggests using `LayoutAnimation` instead of `Animation` to improve performance. However, the documentation is lacking and I cant figure out how to get `LayoutAnimation` to rotate things. I could also stop rendering the spinner during the scene transitions, but I find that this makes things look weird and only solves half the problem.

I can't be the first person with this problem. (1) How has it been solved before? (and/or 2) How can I get `LayoutAnimation` to rotate the spinner?

Comment: Not sure you'd be able to achieve rotation with `LayoutAnimation` in the current version. Have you tried settings `useNativeDriver` to `true`?

Comment: @sooper `useNativeDriver` did the trick. Thank you! If you post your answer below, I'll mark yours as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting `useNativeDriver` to `true` in your animation. `LayoutAnimation` doesn't currently support rotation but there may be [plans for it](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/3450)